# How to Disable already picked item from listview

Tags: android, xml, email, android-edittext, android-contacts

Hi im trying to get emails of my contact in my phone book and set them to edittext.I can get the emails but set me only the first email on my phone book even when i click other person with completed diffrent email.I whant when i click to edittext then to set picket from user email.

when i click this button open my contact list

```
Button buttonPickContact = (Button) findViewById(R.id.contactact_us_btn);
        buttonPickContact.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                intent.setType(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE);
                startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
            }
        });
```

and whit this function i try to set emails to edittext but set me everytime only one email

```
@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
        Cursor cur = cr.query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, null,
                null, null, null);
        // if user got more then one person in his contact list
        if (cur.getCount() > 0) {
            while (cur.moveToNext()) {
                String id = cur.getString(cur
                        .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));
                String name = cur
                        .getString(cur
                                .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME));
                if (Integer
                        .parseInt(cur.getString(cur
                                .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER))) > 0) {

                //  Log.d("NAMEEE:", name);
                //  System.out.println("name : " + name + ", ID : " + id);

                    // get email and type

                    Cursor emailCur = cr.query(
                            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTENT_URI,
                            null,
                            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTACT_ID
                                    + " = ?", new String[] { id }, null);
                    while (emailCur.moveToNext()) {
                        // This would allow you get several email addresses
                        // if the email addresses were stored in an array
                        String email = emailCur
                                .getString(emailCur
                                        .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.DATA));
                        String emailType = emailCur
                                .getString(emailCur
                                        .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.TYPE));

                        contactNumber = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.waitingToAdd_edittext);
                        // contactName.setText(name);
                        contactNumber.setText(email);

                        System.out.println("Email " + email + " Email Type : "
                                + emailType);
                    }
                    emailCur.close();

                }
            }
        }

    }
```

How can i set email what i choose not only one evry time